# Deleting scrollable area in html/css3/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, space

When I make a paragraph appear by changing the width from 0 to anything above 0 (by using jquery), my website creates all this scrollable area with no content.

I used a smooth transition, which makes the paragraph's width smaller and smaller until it disappears, however, in the last moment before disapearing completely, all of the words of the paragraph become a big column of words; when it finally disappears, im left out with a big scrollable area with nothing in it.

I'm unable to delete this useless space, is there any way to fix this?

I just want to know what should I add either in my css file or in my jquery file to avoid this useless space from ruining my site.

Here is the code:

html:

```
<article id="abms">
            <p>
                Mauris vulputate lorem ac nibh rhoncus, eu mattis lorem mattis. Maecenas metus dui, rhoncus eget erat quis, vehicula luctus justo. Aenean vel porta est, tristique mollis metus. Mauris gravida diam sit amet tellus pellentesque hendrerit. Maecenas ut suscipit metus. Nunc vel volutpat est, porta sodales nibh. Pellentesque varius ac massa nec varius.
                Mauris vulputate lorem ac nibh rhoncus, eu mattis lorem mattis. Maecenas metus dui, rhoncus eget erat quis, vehicula luctus justo. Aenean vel porta est, tristique mollis metus. Mauris gravida diam sit amet tellus pellentesque hendrerit. Maecenas ut suscipit metus. Nunc vel volutpat est, porta sodales nibh. Pellentesque varius ac massa nec varius.
            </p>
        </article>
```

css:

```
#abms
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width:0px;
        text-align: justify;
        text-indent: 60px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        margin: 0% 2% 2% 2%;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on("ready",inicio);

function inicio()
    {
        $("#Alb").on("click",mov1);
        $("#Nos").on("click",mov2);
        $("#Us").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#hfi").fadeIn("slow");
    };

function mov1()
    {
        var hide =
            {
                margin:0,
                padding:0,
                overflow:"hidden",
                width:0
            };
        var show =
            {
                width:"42%",
                overflow:"visible",
                padding: "0% 1% 0% 1%"
            };

        $("#Us").css(hide);
        $("#abms").css(show);
    }

function mov2 ()
    {
        var hide =
            {
                margin:0,
                padding:0,
                overflow:"hidden",
                width:0
            };
        var show =
            {
                overflow:"visible",
                margin: "0% 2% 2% 2%",
                padding: "0.05% 2% 0.05% 2%",
                width:"40%"
            };
        $("#abms").css(hide);
        $("#Us").css(show);
    }
```

I didn't put the full code because its not needed.

Comment: We can't really help without seeing some examples/code to go off of

Comment: there you go thanks :D